# While payment using paypal it will return error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-plus

When i use this API "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" for get "approval_url".

It's give error like :

> {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"redirect_urls","issue":"This
>   field required when payment_method is 'paypal'"}],"message":"Invalid
>   request
>
> see details 
>    ","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"e48112ca1cd19"}

I already mention parameter. This is my array.

```
{  
    "intent":"sale",
    "experience_profile_id":"XP-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA",
    "payer":{  
        "payment_method":"paypal"
    },
    "transactions":[  
        {  
            "amount":{  
                "total":"9.00",
                "currency":"EUR"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"redirect_urls":{  
    "return_url":"http://example.com/success",
    "cancel_url":"http:/example.com/error"
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I think the returned error is pretty clear.. you must include the `redirect_urls` parameter when doing the request. It seems it is an array of urls to redirect to

Comment: You put the ending } too early. The object is closed without containing the redirect_urls param

Comment: `{ "intent":"sale", "experience_profile_id":"XP-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA", "payer":{ "payment_method":"paypal" }, "transactions":[ { "amount":{ "total":"9.00", "currency":"EUR" } } ] , "redirect_urls":{ "return_url":"http://example.com/success", "cancel_url":"http:/example.com/error" }}`

Comment: Yes,Got it
Thanks